# Why are there HandlerFunctions in Spring 5 webflux?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive-streams

I am learning the spring 5 webflux and reactive streams. And there are new HandlerFunctions and RouterFunctions to implement the Http requests and response.

and as per the documentations:

> The annotation counterpart to a handler function would be a method with @RequestMapping.

As **@RequestMapping** is quite easy to handle, implement and understand, then why is there a need of more complex and difficult way to handle Http request and response via this HandlerFunctions and RouterFunction utility?

Please suggest.

Comment: In my opinion This is a way of accomodating functional style into Spring Web. There isnt any difference with respect to performance except that handler fucntions looks like spaghetti code :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring WebFlux gives you two different styles: annotations and functional.

Depending on the type of application that you'd like to build, the constraints that you have to deal with - one or the other might be more relevant. You can even mix both in the same application.

The annotation-based model is very successful, but it also comes with a few limitations, mostly because of Java annotations themselves:

- the code path is not always clear, unless you know the internals of Spring Framework (do you know where handler mappings are detected? matched against incoming requests?)
- it's using reflection, which has a cost
- it can be hard to debug and extend

The functional variant tries to fix those issues and embrace a functional style (with the JDK8 function API) and immutability. It's got a "more library; less framework" touch to it, meaning that you're more in control of things. Here's an example: with `RouterFunction`, you can chain `RequestPredicates` and they are executed in order, so you're in full control of what ultimately handles the incoming request. With the annotations model, the most specific handler will be selected, by looking at the annotations on the method and the incoming request.

If you're perfectly happy with the annotations model, there's no reason to switch. But again, you can mix both and maybe you'll find the functional model handy. In my opinion, trying it even if you don't plan on adopting it won't hurt - worst case scenario this will broaden a bit your perspective as a developer and show you a different way of doing things.

For more on that, you can check out [Arjen Poutsma's talk on the functional web framework in Spring WebFlux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upFFlGq5-NU).

Answer (score 0):

It's not needed, and doesn't break webflux.  I'd use `@RequestMapping`, if you don't have special needs making HandlerFunction neccessary.

For RouterFunctions: If you don't want to use JSON parsing, and want to modify the ServerRequest directly (e.g. have the raw InputStream), you'd have to use the RouterFunctions (AFAIK).  You'd then return a raw stream (Mono), too.  I had a case, where I needed to play proxy with a little bit extra, and thus needed to avoid the JSON parsing, that you'd usually have with `@RequestMapping`